# Get measure for selected vector objects in Openlayers 4

Tags: openlayers

I need to get area and edge size values from selected object on the map. I worked on this code below. But I can not find the how i get these values.

```
function(polygon) {
    var area = ol.Sphere.getArea(polygon);
    var output;
    if (area > 10000) {
      output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
    } else {
      output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
    }
    return output;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you the sample from OpenLayers example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqKbaB?editors=0010

```
select.on('select', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = formatArea(e.selected[0].getGeometry());
});
```

`e.selected[0].getGeometry()` returns `ol.geom.Polygon`.

Comment: its really helpful, i will try this and add here complete solution, thank you.